# Associate file in java for sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm working with java and I would like to associate key from a class to another and display it.

I have 2 classes:

class 'car' containing:

```
car_id, wheel, other
```

class 'wheel' containing:

```
wheel_id, param1, param2
```

Here is 'car_manager' in order to view in sqlite database 'car' with wheel_id (related to wheel):

```
public ArrayList<CarManager> getCarManager() {
    ArrayList<CarManager> ListCarManager = new ArrayList<CarManager>();
    String query = "SELECT car_id, wheel_id, other FROM CAR_DB ORDER BY car_id";
    try {
        this.main.getDatabase().connect();
        ResultSet rslt = this.main.getDatabase().getResultOf(query);
        while (rslt.next()) {
            ListCarManager.add(new Car
                    (rslt.getLong("car_id"),
                            rslt.getLong("wheel_id"),
                            rslt.getString("other"),
                    ));
        }
        rslt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        this.main.getDatabase().disconnect();
    }
    return ListCarManager;
}
```

However I have a conflict because 'wheel_id' is a long and 'car' contains class 'wheel'.
I would like to keep class wheel into car. I have tried different things without success:

```
        Long wheel_id = car.getWheel.getId();

        rslt.setLong(i++, car.getWheel.getId("wheel_id"),
```

Comment: You need to also read the wheel table, create a new wheel instance and then assign that new instance to your also newly created car instance.

Comment: I would beware of trying to reinvent ORM. Your time would be much better invested in learning and using an existing ORM framework. Also, don't use [underscores](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) in Java variable names - just constants (upper case). And anything before 'id' in your ID variable names is redundant

Comment: thank you for your comment @
Seelenvirtuose
 I've tried to add to the code:  

    `public Wheel wheel;`

    `Long wheel_id = wheel.getWheel_id();`

    `rslt.getLong("wheel_id"),`

but I still can't achieve my goal